# select the master table and relation table where by some column id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I don't know it is possible or not only with sql.

what I want to do is select the master table and relation table where by some column id

```
 product_id |   product    
-------------------+-------------
          21 | Milk    
          26 | HeadPhone    
          25 | TV
```

```
 product_id |   custom_id
-------------------+----------
         21 | 213    
         26 | 245
         26 | 229
         25 | 245
         25 | 244
```

is it possible to find by custom_id,

Below is something likes `where custom_id = 245`

```
 product_id |   product    | custom_id
------------+-------------+---------
         26 | HeadPhone    |  245,229
         25 | TV    |  245,244
```

Comment: I m using postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure I understand the part "*something likes where custom_id = 245*", but maybe you are looking for something this.

```
select mt.product_id, 
       mt.product, 
       string_agg(rt.custom_id::text, ',' order by rt.custom_id desc) as custom_ids
from master_table mt
  join relation_table rt on mt.product_id = rt.product_id
where exists (select *
             from relation_table mt2 
             where mt2.product_id = mt.product_id
               and mt2.custom_id = 245)
group by mt.product_id, mt.product;
```

Comment: Thanks this should be answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using posgres version 8.4 or higher you can make use of the [array_arg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html) function.

The `array_arg` function returns an array but it can be casted into text.

```
SELECT t1.product_id, t1.product, array_agg(t2.custom_id)
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
WHERE t1.product_id = t2.product_id
```

If you are using postgres version 9.0 or higher you can make use of the [string_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) function and your query could look like this

```
SELECT t1.product_id, t1.product, string_agg(t2.custom_id, ',')
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
WHERE t1.product_id = t2.product_id
```